# Express res.jsonp returns two callback names to Safari Extension AJAX call

Tags: ajax, express, jsonp

I'm building an extension in Safari, using Express.js on the back end. I make an AJAX call to the server, and the server responds with what appears to be a double callback name:

```
jQuery191026131771644577384_1364321159940 && jQuery191026131771644577384_1364321159940([
  {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
]);
```

Here's the AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    data : { 'something': 'something more'},
    url :  "http://localhost:3001/api/login/?callback=?",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data, text){
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + status + error );
    }  
});
```

...and here's the Express.js:

```
app.get('/api/login', function(req, res){
  res.jsonp([{'foo':'bar'}]);
});
```

The browser is reporting a parse error, likely because of the double callback stamp above.

Clues?

Comment: Try removing callback=? from the URL. dataType:'jsonp' takes care of adding that for you.

Comment: thanks, that worked. running into other issues now :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a double callback, it's the same as doing `func && func()`, it just makes sure that the function exists before calling it, so avoid throwing an exception.

Comment: @user508708 He's right about not needing `callback=?`, but your example response only has one function in it.

Comment: it's the same function x 2, making it two functions to the browser. it was choking on the concatenation.

Comment: @bear It's not concatenation, the first `func` will return false if the function doesn't exist. It's the same as `if (func) func();`

Comment: If you are still getting a parse error, could you add the error text to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Hector has it right in the comments: Try removing callback=? from the URL